# Errors deploying Java + Groovy mixed code on Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, groovy

I'm trying to deploy a project on Heroku but I'm getting Maven compilaton errors like this:

> remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_5d64555c50abcb9638e3ef5b331a0107/src/main/java/com/davioooh/myapp/services/TestService.java:[3,43] package com.davioooh.myapp.domain does not exist

In my project I'm using both Java and Groovy classes. All Groovy classes are in `com.davioooh.myapp.domain` that can't be found during compilation.

I also tried to move all Groovy classe in `src/main/groovy` folder but it's still not working...

Is there a way to correctly deploy my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved adding [Groovy Eclipse Maven Plugin](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin) as compiler plugin in my project *pom.xml*.

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1-01</version>
          </dependency>
          <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7-01</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```